# How to keep Wifi Direct Turned ON Android

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I don't know if its in native API or just my GS3. Wifi direct is automatically turned OFF after 5 minutes of inactivity. Is there is any way of keeping it on? or turn it On programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862018/startscan-has-result-after-10-min-when-phone-get-into-idle-state

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Wi-Fi lock:

```
WifiLock wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
    .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock");

wifiLock.acquire();
```

When you no longer need the network, you should release the lock:

```
wifiLock.release();
```

Comment: I think you don't understand me I am talking about "Wifi Direct" which is added in android 4+ when I turn on the wifi direct I will automatically turned off after sometime

Comment: Yeap sorry I tought you wanted to keep normal WiFi :)