# startscan() has result after 10 min when phone get into idle state

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager, network-scan

I am trying to scan wifi networks every 2 minutes. I am using service for that. When the phone is "active" or "in use" after `startscan()` called I get `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION` in 6 sec. So i can scan for wifis periodically. But after the phone has not been touched by anyone for a certain time (10 min) startscan() stops "working" and only after 10 min getting result. Anybody experienced this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3874375/1342413) I have found the solution - this is because [the Wifi sleep policy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_DEFAULT).
You can set your wifi device never goes to sleep with this:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
              Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, 
              Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER);
```

Be sure, that you added this permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

the scanning period will be 5-15s - and this is automatic - you dont need to call `startscan()`. more info about Android scanning process can be found [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37621/where-can-i-find-settings-for-wifi-internal-scan-period).
**Edit:**
maybe this is even better solution if you only want to scan for hotspots:
[`WIFI_MODE_SCAN_ONLY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_MODE_SCAN_ONLY) - it can be activated by:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiLock wifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_SCAN_ONLY , "MyWifiLock");
if(!wifiLock.isHeld()){
    wifiLock.acquire();
}
```

dont forget to release it, more info about `WifiLock` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html)
also define this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

**Edit2** this works as well:
you can enable, and disable wifi periodically:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if(wm.isWifiEnabled() == false) {
    wm.setWifiEnabled(true);
}
```

then scan after your broadcastreceiver gets the action containing `WIFI_STATE_ENABLED` extra

Comment: +1 nice - see my question on `getScanResults();` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137268/wifimanager-getscanresults-clarifications-automatic-scans-sleep-etc). Also - suppose you enable wireless, then you want to redisable it after scanning - what if the user had enabled it while you were scanning (so you should not disable it) ? Is there a way to know ?