# WifiManager.getScanResults() - clarifications (automatic scans, sleep etc)

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-wireless

I would like some clarifications on the behavior of `WifiManager.getScanResults()`, namely :

*When wireless is enabled*

1. Does android scan for access points on a fixed interval ? Can one query/change the interval ? Can one query the time of the last scan ? For a discussion see this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/37646)
2. What happens when the wireless radio is turned off (sleeps) - while wifi is still enabled - will `getScanResults()` go on returning the last scan results ? How would one know if it's time for `startScan()`?

*When wireless is disabled*

1. `getScanResults()` would return the last scan results ? Or an empty List ? Or `null` (it does return null at times and this is not handled by 90%  of the snippets posted in SO) ?
2. The answer to 1 would be true even after a reboot (the phone booting with wifi off) ?

The reason I ask is I need to get the list of the available access points periodically and I'd rather call `getScanResults()` at once, than `WifiManager.startScan()` and then `getScanResults()` if I really do not have to - as this involves acquiring wifi locks and the like and is rather subtle. I am not also sure how much do the API level and phone hardware come into play.

For a good discussion of difficulties see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862018/startscan-has-result-after-10-min-when-phone-get-into-idle-state/14910918#14910918)

Comment: what do you mean on: " How would one know if it's time for startScan()?"

Comment: @laplasz: I mean - I _guess_ `getScanResults()` will return the same results after CPU goes to bed AND/OR wifi radio is turned off - so how would I know this (getScanResults() returns the same results - those of the last scan) and initiate a `startScan()` ? _Assuming_ `getScanResults()` will keep returning the same results. There are no docs on the behavior of `getScanResults()` once the phone has gone to bed - and before that there are no docs on the automatic scans that are performed

Comment: why don't you perform a `startscan()` before calling the `getScanResults()`

Answer (score 3):

*When wireless is disabled*

1. `getScanResults()` will return `null`...
2. ...even after a reboot (that's to be expected - this would be disputed if it did not return null in the first place)

*When wireless is enabled*

2.Surprisingly enough `getScanResults()` will return `null` after some time (on a Nexus One, Android 2.3.7, Cyanogen mod - but I suspect this is not really relevant). So yes, apparently one has to initiate a scan irrespective of the wireless status

I guess this is true also if the state is `WIFI_STATE_DISABLING`

I am still interested in the answer in the case wireless is enabled - in particular question 2, if the device is asleep. Google groups won't let me post (hint)

Answer (score -2):

> public List getScanResults ()

Added in **API LEVEL 1**

*Return the results of the latest access point scan.*

Returns
the list of access points found in the most recent scan. An app must hold `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission in order to get valid results.